# Check for email address

Tags: powershell

I have been using `[mailaddress]$SourceEmail -ne $null`

```
Try {
    [mailaddress]$SourceEmail -ne $null
}
Catch { Do stuff}
```

The problem I am having is if `$SourceEmail` is `null` or `""` the output is "false"

How can I test if the variable is an email address and if not an email address have the catch portion do it's thing?

Comment: You can test for multiple conditions with an `if` statement.

Comment: I thought of that but if you put ```[mailaddress]$SourceEmail -ne $null``` in a ```If``` you will get an error blast @DanielMann

Comment: @DanielMann example ```If ([mailaddress]$SourceEmail -ne $null ){Write-Host "Good" -ForegroundColor Green}else {Write-Host "Bad" -ForegroundColor red}``` 
= error if $SourceEmail = 'Pete'

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer @DanielMann in the comments made me remember I had a different way to test for email address

```
   if ($SourceEmail -as [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress]) {
            $CheckSource = 'Good'
        }
        else {
            $CheckSource = 'bad'
        }
```

This does not make an error if `$null` or `""` or if the `$SourceEmail` is anything but valid.

Comment: You should use booleans for this, i.e. `$isValid = $true` or `$isValid = $false`.

Comment: Oh yeah my actual code is like ```while (!($SourceEmail -as [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress])) {
        write-host "Hit enter to break. "  -ForegroundColor red  -NoNewline
        write-host "Enter source email address" -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
        $SourceEmail = Read-Host " ?"
        if ($SourceEmail -eq "") {
            Return Write-Host "Enter was inputed" -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor White
        }
    }``` @DanielMann I was just trying to highlight doing stuff.

Comment: besides the typo inputted :)